# How I can define default start option for vim? (not vimscript)

Tags: vim

I need options exactly, **not vimscript**.

For ex. I have small `.vimrc` file with vimscript stuff. But I also want to run vim with `-p` option every time. Not want to do it by hand. I already tried write `-p` at first line, before `syntax on` in my `.vimrc` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In bash `alias vim='vim -p'`?

Comment: i guess your goal is to make switching between files clearer. you don't have to do in all in tabs. there are plugins out there to easier your life: https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim

Comment: There is no such option. You will need to script something, use a wrapper/alias to launch Vim, or just start using the command manually.

Comment: @FDinoff, thanks man. This's exactly what i need. I hoped to keep vim logic in `.vimrc` separate but looks like changing `.bashrc` much much simpler way. 

@HuStmpHrrr, yep you guess, i often use tabs everyday. I really not happy to use regular buffers because it little bit hard to keep on screen only required files and switch between them as fast as I can. Looks like your plugin resolve this problem. I'll try it out, thanks

Comment: There's nothing fast in moving your hand to the mouse, search for the tab with the name you're looking for and finally clicking on it. Learn to use `ctrl-d` together with `:buf` or install ctrlP plugin, it will be much faster!